# Issue in sending HTTP post using jmeter for approx 16mb of ofx data

Tags: jmeter

How to send HTTP post using jmeter for approx 16mb of ofx data? for one thread data is posted successfully but for multiple threads load test stops after execution of first thread. I am sending this data in the body of POST request. Also I need parameterized few of the data in ofx file data.

Just to clarify, I know how to post HTTP request with huge ofx data. But problem I am facing is- for one thread it works fine. My application takes around 25 mins to process that much data. But, in case I increase the number of threads in JMeter testplan with some ramp up time only one thread executes and jmeter stops executing next thread. Pl suggest the solution.

Comment: Just to clarify, I know how to post HTTP request with huge ofx data. But problem I am facing is- for one thread it works fine. My application takes around 25 mins to process that much data. But, in case I increase the number of threads in JMeter testplan with some ramp up time only one thread executes and jmeter stops executing next thread. Pl suggest the solution.

Comment: Can you give more details about issue ? Show jmeter.log file content, show a screenshot of your Test Plan ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the HTTP request connect/response timeouts?
If not, this could be the solution for your issue!

Answer (score 0):

This issue generally occurs due to insufficient memory/heap
The best way to overcome this issue is to increase the heap size in jmeter.bat file

From:
"set HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"

To:
set HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx2048m

Hope this will help.